# In-place variable declaration with template classes

Tags: c++, templates

Imagine the structure

```cpp
struct regular {};
```

and

```cpp
template <class>
struct templated {};
```

So, is there a way to declare variable of type templated in the same way as in `regular` structure?

For example, the first thing I tried was:

```cpp
struct regular {} /* CV */ variable; /// This is clear.

template <>
struct templated<void*> {} /* CV */ var2; /// But this don't.
```

Of course, I can't do it this way. C++ standard doesn't say anything about it, unless I didn't read carefully.

Comment: You want a single variable with type `templated<void*>`, or a variable template which can instantiate as a different variable for each type?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5MeT8KhPh) it?

Comment: There is no "*type templated*", it's a *template* from which types can be instantiated. Also, `template <>` is template specialization syntax. To avoid wasting any more time, I suggest to stop here and read a good [C++ Book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

Taking *attr-* related aside. According to the *Declarations* in [N4695](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#nt:simple-declaration):

> simple-declaration:
>
> - decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list;

> decl-specifier-seq:
>
> - decl-specifier decl-specifier-seq

> decl-specifier:
>
> - storage-class-specifier
> - defining-type-specifier
> - function-specifier
> - friend
> - typedef
> - constexpr
> - inline

***template-declaration* is not included.**

For an ordinary class, it's possible, since it's a *class-spcifier*, is a kind of *defining-type-specifier* somehow.

```cpp
struct regular {} variable; // decl-specifier-seq is "struct regular {}"
```

Put it simply, the syntax is disabled.